В чём разница между npm и npx
Я уде перечитал кучку статей но всёравно не могу понять зачем его (npx) используют.
"npx дает возможность исполнять пакеты Node. js временно, без необходимости установки" и спрашивается в чём проблема из устанавливать.

Спрашиваете, в чем проблема их установки? Это очевидно. Проблема может возникать, когда что-то в новом пакете конфликтует с уже ранее установленным.


и спрашивается в чём проблема их устанавливать.

Никаких проблем нет. Если хотите, устанавливайте.

Просто есть такие npm пакеты которые за проект выполняются один раз (создание нового проекта через create-react-app, миграция БД через knex migrate, сиды sequelize db:seed и т.д.) поэтому и смысл их устанавливать отпадает. В таких случаях и используют npx.
Может быть случай когда вы не хотите устанавливать пакет локально или глобально.
У вас нет разрешения на глобальную установку.
Иногда вам может понадобиться команда сценария (создать, преобразовать что-то,...) в package.json, чтобы выполнить что-то без установки этих пакетов в качестве зависимостей проекта.

А если короче.
npm — менеджер пакетов для JavaScript, как например: pip для (Python), Maven для (Java), NuGet для  (.NET), Composer для  (PHP), RubyGems для  (Ruby).
npx — запускает команду пакета без его установки.
